# Inhomogeneous second order DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When my second order DE is inhomogeneous, it has a $f(x)$ on the right hand side...

I know that if $f(x)$ is of the form

$f(x) = a^x * p(x)$

then my "guess" of a particular solution that solves the DE would be something like

$a^x * q(x)$

But there are two things I don't quite get.

1) What degree would $q(x)$ have? What would it depend on?

2) What if there was no $p(x)$, just a $a^x$. What would my "guess" on a particular solution then be?

Comment: It would be nice to see your DE and not only words "second order DE"

Answer (score 1):

1:  Q will have the same (full) degree of p,  so if P is a 3rd degree, you need full, generic 3rd degree polynomial.   Then you need to multiply that polynomial by ADDITIONAL factors of x for overlapping roots,   i.e. each time $a^x$ is a solution of your homogeneous equation, you need to add a factor of x.    Example:

$y''+2y'+y=x^2e^{-x}$.
Here, your homogeneous equation has a double root at $r=-1$,  so you start with a full polynomial of degree 2 $ax^2+bx+c$ then multiply by $x^2$  (squared because it was a double root),  to get a particular solution of the form $(ax^4+bx^3+cx^2)e^{-x}$

2:  If there's no solution, then you stick with $ca^x$, with extra factors of $x$ multiplied for each time $a^x$  is a solution of your homogeneous.